# How to globally update npm so new Angular projects are created with the desired version?

Tags: angular, npm

My installation of `npm` currently sets up new projects with Angular 16. How do I tell it to always set up new projects with Angular 17 (and the other dependencies appropriately updated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install angular core latest also

```
npm install -g @angular/core@latest
```

You need to update your cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

If the cli requires latest versions of npm or node.js

1. [node.js download link](https://nodejs.org/en/download)
2. ```
   npm install -g npm@latest
   ```

after that if you do `ng new` you will get the latest version of angular!

Comment: I had to first do `npm install -g @angular/core@latest` or it doesn't work.

Comment: @user66554 added to my answer!